# What is the difference between Ehrenfest dynamics and Born-Oppenheimer Molecular Dynamics?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, ab-initio-calculations, quantum-dynamics

What is the fundamental difference(s) between Ehrenfest dynamics and Born-Oppenheimer MD? Also, in what situation(s) or case(s) one is preferred than the other one?

Comment: +1. Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1523/5

Comment: Also related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/what-are-the-types-of-quantum-molecular-dynamics-qmd

Comment: The question was closed at the request of the asker, but if anyone has more detail they'd like to put, which would be more appropriate here rather than in the above marked question in the duplicate notification, they are welcome to comment here or here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55164099#55164099 and we can re-open the question.